# Making badly scanned public domain books legible with OCR

Tags: ocr

I've obtained soft copies of some very old public domain books.

The illustrations are clear enough, but the text is somewhat blurry.

I've experimented with Tesseract OCR and it can recognize a surprising amount of the words with some errors, but it spits them out into a jumbled mess in a separate file.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to have Tesseract or another OCR recognize the text and then place it over the original blurry text without changing other elements such as lines and illustrations?
2. And, if this is possible, is it also possible to have Tesseract or another OCR mimic the varying sizes, fonts, and colors of the original text?

Thank you!

Comment: [OCRmyPDF](https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF) may be worth looking at.  It's a python program that wraps around tesseract and can do useful things like attempting to de-skew or rotate or clean up each page before passing it to tesseract.   It creates a new pdf with the text embedded (text can be extracted with, e.g., `pdftotext`...or, for multi-column text, `pdftotext --layout`).

Comment: Thank you! I will give those suggestions a try. OCRmyPDF is new to me. I've used pdftotext before but was unaware of the --layout option. Thank you!

Comment: actually, my mistake, it's just `-layout` with a single `-`.